# Velocity Template Issue With Apostrophe's

Tags: java, apache, velocity

I am using a Velocity template, and when I use a variable with an apostrophe, i.e.:

`$user's`

where "user" is the variable name, I get the value for the variable translated, but the apostrophe turns into a bunch of question marks.  For instance, if the value for "user" was "Mary Ann," I'd get this:

`Mary Ann????s`

How can I "escape" the apostrophe so that the Velocity **mergeTemplate** method will not produce this output?  BTW, the encoding that I'm sending to that method is **iso-8859-1**:

`Velocity.mergeTemplate(template, TEMPLATE_ENCODING, context, string_writer);`

Although we don't have a Velocity properties file, it's my understanding that this is the default Velocity encoding.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I can use the encoding **`amp#39;`** in the HTML template but I still have the same issue in the text template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this template used in context of HTML you can use `&rsquo;`

Comment: See my update above.  But thanks for the quick response!  The plain text template still has the same issue.  When trying to use the encoding in my update above, I get the literal encoding syntax, rather than an apostrophe.

Comment: I must not have properly committed my template, because it now processes the plain text apostrophe without attempting to convert it, i.e. not showing "???."  Since your answer involved replacing an apostrophe with an ISO-8859-1 encoding, I'll give you the credit, even though it was the wrong encoding.  ;)